# Show path of links

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

Didn't know how to explain my Problem in the title...

Easy example of my Problem.

First page a gridview of a Country table with links on the Country names. After you click on a Country you come to a new gridview with all the states from this Country and if you click on one state you get all the cities of the state on the next page and so on.

I want to somehow Show all the steps (links) i make in a horisontal list over my gridview so i can stay oriented in wich Country im looking at and that i always have the possibility to fast go back one or two steps in the "hierarchy".

Lets say im looking at a gridview with info about Miami then i want that i have a list with the links i used over my gridview like this

USA --> California  Like this i can orient myself and also go back to the USA Grid with only one click.

Is there some easy solution for this?

Sorry for bad Explanation of my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a sitemap file to the project and SiteMapPath control to the page(s)

sitemapfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode title="Country" description="Country" url="~/webform1.aspx" >
      <siteMapNode title="State" description="States" url="~/webform1.aspx?t=state">
        <siteMapNode title="City" description="Cities" url="~/Webform3.aspx" />
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

SiteMapPath control

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in every step you have the selected values from the previous steps, so you can show the proper results. Than you can use a LinkButton and show the selected values with links.